# How do you convert HTML to plain text in Acumatica for use in reports and inquiries?

Tags: acumatica

Is there any easy way to convert the body text from an activity, task or other HTML field in Acumatica into a readable format that shows well in a report or generic inquiry? I could create a SQL function to strip out the HTML, a SQL View containing the stripped code, and then add that object to Acumatica but I'm looking for a simpler, more native way.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom attribute that subscribes to the FieldSelecting event to dynamically convert the field to plain text. There are many ways to do the actual conversion, but I would recommend using HtmlAgilityPack, an open-source library that already ships with Acumatica to do the work.

Here's how I would define the attribute:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using HtmlAgilityPack;

namespace PX.Data
{  
  [PXString(IsUnicode = true)]
  public class HtmlToTextAttribute : PXAggregateAttribute, IPXFieldSelectingSubscriber
  {
    protected Type _htmlField;
  
    public HtmlToTextAttribute(Type htmlField)
    {
      if (htmlField == null) {
        throw new PXArgumentException(nameof(htmlField), ErrorMessages.ArgumentNullException);
      }
      
      _htmlField = htmlField;
    }
  
    public virtual void FieldSelecting(PXCache sender, PXFieldSelectingEventArgs e)
    {
      var html = sender.GetValue(e.Row, _htmlField.Name) as string;
      if(!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(html))
      {
        e.ReturnValue = ConvertToPlainText(html);
      }
    }
    
    //Source: https://github.com/ceee/ReadSharp/blob/master/ReadSharp/HtmlUtilities.cs
    public static string ConvertToPlainText(string html)
    {
      HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
      doc.LoadHtml(html);

      StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
      ConvertTo(doc.DocumentNode, sw);
      sw.Flush();
      return sw.ToString();
    }

    private static void ConvertContentTo(HtmlNode node, TextWriter outText)
    {
      foreach (HtmlNode subnode in node.ChildNodes)
      {
        ConvertTo(subnode, outText);
      }
    }
        
    private static void ConvertTo(HtmlNode node, TextWriter outText)
    {
      string html;
      switch (node.NodeType)
      {
        case HtmlNodeType.Comment:
          // don't output comments
          break;

        case HtmlNodeType.Document:
          ConvertContentTo(node, outText);
          break;

        case HtmlNodeType.Text:
          // script and style must not be output
          string parentName = node.ParentNode.Name;
          if ((parentName == "script") || (parentName == "style"))
            break;

          // get text
          html = ((HtmlTextNode)node).Text;

          // is it in fact a special closing node output as text?
          if (HtmlNode.IsOverlappedClosingElement(html))
            break;

          // check the text is meaningful and not a bunch of whitespaces
          if (html.Trim().Length > 0)
          {
            outText.Write(HtmlEntity.DeEntitize(html));
          }
          break;

        case HtmlNodeType.Element:
          switch (node.Name)
          {
            case "p":
              // treat paragraphs as crlf
              outText.Write("\r\n");
              break;
            case "br":
              outText.Write("\r\n");
              break;
          }

          if (node.HasChildNodes)
          {
            ConvertContentTo(node, outText);
          }
          break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

To use this attribute, just define a new (non-persisted) field and decorate it with the HtmlToText attribute, for example as an extension on the CRActivity table:

```
    #region UsrBodyText
    [HtmlToText(typeof(CRActivity.body))]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName="Body (text)")]
    public virtual string UsrBodyText { get; set; }
    public abstract class usrBodyText : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<usrBodyText> { }
    #endregion
```